# How can I change MaxValueLength of NewValue and OriginalValue in EntityPropertyChange.cs?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

I am using aspnetzero and I have enabled entity history. Maxvaluelength of NewValue and OriginalValue is 512 chars in AbpEntityPropertyChanges table.
How can I change MaxValueLength of NewValue and OriginalValue?

Update -
Below is the way tried extending entity, but still its truncating characters after 512.

```
public class EntityPropertyChangeExtended : EntityPropertyChange
{
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    [StringLength(8000)]
    public override string NewValue { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    [StringLength(8000)]
    public override string OriginalValue { get; set; }

    public override void SetNewValue(string newValue)
    {
        NewValueHash = newValue?.ToMd5();
        NewValue = newValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use to set original value. (Also fills <see cref="OriginalValueHash"/> according to <paramref name="originalValue"/>)
    /// </summary>
    public override void SetOriginalValue(string originalValue)
    {
        OriginalValueHash = originalValue?.ToMd5();
        OriginalValue = originalValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not possible. See [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#4203](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/4203).

Comment: @aaron, I changed the schema from backend directly and  tried extending EntityPropertyChange.cs, and overring set value methods but that didn't work. Is there any way out to do it? Characters are getting truncated after 512 chars.

Comment: @aaron, updated question with code for above comment.